# Is it possible to get a collection containing the attributes of all entities (customers, products, etc)?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav

I'm trying to get a collection from the table `eav/attribute` (where product's attributes are present along with customer's, category's, etc).

I already tried to retrieve it like a normal model collection:

```php
$entitiesAttributes = Mage::getModel('eav/attribute')->getCollection();
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot instantiate abstract class Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute

Because, of course, the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute` is abstract. Is there a way to do it with collections?

Or I should do it directly with SQL?

```sql
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` ...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can use `Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot :)